# How can i simulate a car with ROS and Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create my own robot car model and simulate, the steering, the power unit, etc.

I'm a novice in ROS and Gazebo.

Please tell me about this problem detail. And Where could i find a documentation for dummies or Step by Step?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10623/how-can-i-simulate-a-car-with-ros-and-gazebo?/) by [mangoya](https://answers.ros.org/users/785/mangoya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-07-17

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of our students created an experimental [art_gazebo_plugins](http://code.google.com/p/utexas-art-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fsandbox%2Fstacks%2Fart_experimental%2Fart_gazebo_plugins) package for the ART autonomous vehicle in the sandbox branch of the `utexas-art-ros-package` repository.

That implementation is specific to our vehicle and not complete, but it does run and may be helpful, given the lack of good gazebo documentation.

There is probably enough demand within the ROS community to justify creating some shared packages for car-like simulation and navigation. As always, the challenge is creating a team with the interest and time to make it happen.

UPDATE: there is now a [ROS Ackermann group](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Ackermann%20Group) for defining interfaces and sharing code.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jkolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/10551/jkolb/) on 2014-02-10**:
Has there been an update to this in the last 3.5 years? We have a car-like vehicle that currently uses JAUS and are looking to move to ROS. It's an outside vehicle with GPS/IMU/Velodyne, teleop and some autonomy. We like the idea of ROS but don't quite know how to start for this type of vehicle.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-02-11**:
@Jim Rothrock has some tools, see http://answers.ros.org/question/10265/gazebo-ackermann-car-simulation/  and https://github.com/jim-rothrock/gazebo_ros_pkgs .

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on 2014-02-11**:
Took a look at the ackermann_vehicle metapackage: http://wiki.ros.org/ackermann_vehicle?distro=hydro

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a good start for using `gazebo` http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find some answers [here](http://answers.ros.org/questions/?tags=Ackermann&start_over=true) (questions regarding Ackermann steering).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1